# if else statement with multiple conditions (and)

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a problem with a if else statement. 
I have a collection which sort by 2 different tags: material and size. 
I want an heading and paragraph to show, when neither a material or material and size is chosen. 
You can see the collection here: https://www.sengefabriksudsalg.dk/collections/madrasser/

I have tried this:

```
{% if pageValues contains 'Latexmadrasser' %}
<h2 class="mat-h2-collecion">Latexmadrasser</h2>
<p> Hello </p>

{% elsif pageValues contains 'Latexmadrasser' and '70x200'  %}
<h2 class="mat-h2-collecion">Latexmadrasser 70x200</h2>
<p> Hello </p>

{% endif %}
```

But it prints only the first statement :(

Comment: If the first clause is true, the second clause will never be evaluated.

Comment: I've removed the `ruby` tag because this is about the _Liquid_ template language. Although Liquid is written in Ruby, it has its own syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Re-order your clauses from most to least specific. Your second clause would only ever be evaluated if `pageValue` does **not** include 'Latexmadrasser', since this condition would already be enough to satisfy the first `if`, so you'll never reach the `elif`.

```
{% if pageValues contains 'Latexmadrasser' and pageValues contains '70x200' %}
<h2 class="mat-h2-collecion">Latexmadrasser 70x200</h2>
<p> Hello </p>

{% elsif pageValues contains 'Latexmadrasser' %}
<h2 class="mat-h2-collecion">Latexmadrasser</h2>
<p> Hello </p>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: `{% if pageValues contains 'Latexmadrasser' and '70x200' %}` or `{% if pageValues contains 'Latexmadrasser' and pageValues contains '70x200' %}` ?

Comment: Probably the latter, my main concern here was the order of statements, but I'll update the post.

Comment: Thanks,

I have a new hurdle and hope for help again.

{% if pageValues contains 'Skummadrasser' and pageValues contains '80x200' %}
<h2> Write this </h2>

{% elsif pageValues contains 'Skummadrasser' and pageValues contains '180x200' %}
<h2> Write this </h2>

{% elsif pageValues == blank %}
<h2> Write this </h2>

Right now, only 80x200 and blank text are printed on the collection page. If I press 180x200 tag, the text to 80x200 will be shown.

Comment: Please open a new question for this, a comment is not really the place for it.

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't this be:

```
if pageValues contains 'Latexmadrasser' and pageValues contains '70x200'
```

my liquid is not up to date though.

Comment: Correct, the second half in the original question is an invalid construct